# Problem with usb's on CentOS

Tags: centos

I have problem to recognize my USB devices on the CentOS 5.9(Final).
Here are all the appropriate commands.

> dmesg | grep usb

```
usbcore: registered new driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new driver hub
usbcore: registered new driver hiddev
usbcore: registered new driver usbhid
drivers/usb/input/hid-core.c: v2.6:USB HID core driver
usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 2, error -110
usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 3, error -110
usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 4, error -110
usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 5, error -110
usbcore: registered new driver usb-storage
```

> lspci | grep USB

```
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 0c)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB Enhanced Host Controller (rev 0c)
```

> lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 0000:0000
```

> uname -a

```
Linux @@@@@@@@@ 2.6.18-348.1.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Jan 22 16:24:03 EST 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://urukrama.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/usb-drive-not-recognised-error-71/) yet?

Comment: No, I didn't try it! I will come back with the result when I will do it. Thanks!

Comment: @Bratchley I have try the link you mention, but I still have the same problem!